# How to properly expose Windows form object to other classes

Tags: wpf, vb.net, vsto

I have a basic question. I'm creating a VSTO Word Addin. I have a Ribbon button which opens a WPF dialog box called TableSelector. It is hosted in a Windows form.

```
Public Class RibbonControl

Private f As Form

Private Sub btnSelectTable_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles btnSelectTable.Click
    Dim h As New System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost()
    Dim tableselector1 As New TableSelector
    f = New Form()
    f.MaximumSize = New Size(500, 380)
    f.MinimumSize = New Size(500, 380)
    f.MaximizeBox = False
    f.Name = "HostForm"
    h.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    h.Child = tableselector1
    f.Controls.Add(h)
    f.Show()
    f.TopMost = True
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property hostForm() As Form
    Get
        Return f
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

Then I have a close button on that WPF control to close the dialog box. When I click it I get runtime error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on line 3 of the below code.

```
Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Dim ribbon As New RibbonControl()
    ribbon.hostForm.Close()
End Sub
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for get the specific window for close

```
Window win = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.Name == "Window Name");
win.Close();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. I don't understand the use of the SingleOrDefault method. What does "w" represent?

Comment: Did you check if this code is working?
SingleOrDefault checks the collection of windows and returns a single window instance as per the specified condition ie (w => w.Name == "Window Name") . It means it will select a window **w** from windows collection where **w.Name** equals **some string value that corresponds to your window name**. You need to learn LINQ and LAMBDA expressions more.

Comment: I cannot try it because 1) it's in C# and 2) Addin projects are different. For example, the Application object available within an VSTO addin has no Current method. I tried to query the Globals.ThisAddin.Application.Windows collection but it does not contain the dialog box at all. Only opened documents. I would prefer fixing the code posted above.

Comment: Changing the f variable from Private to Public Shared solved the problem. Thank you for trying to help me out.